# Why Jenkins failure with Error : Exit 9009

Tags: jenkins, katalon-studio

I am trying to deploy a Katalon Testcase to Jenkins but some errors appear, such as:

- **is not recognized as an internal or external command**
- Exit 9009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkin using old update jenkin.war 
You should Update file at : https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#installing-docker

WAR file
The Web application ARchive (WAR) file version of Jenkins can be installed on any operating system or platform that supports Java.

To download and run the WAR file version of Jenkins:

Download the latest stable Jenkins WAR file to an appropriate directory on your machine.

Open up a terminal/command prompt window to the download directory.

Run the command java -jar jenkins.war.

Browse to http://localhost:8080 and wait until the Unlock Jenkins page appears.

Continue on with the Post-installation setup wizard below.

Solve it well